# Export view to Excel or PDF using mvc core and razor

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

We are trying to export both partial and complete views to Excel. The code almost produce what we want but we have a problem that we must get fixed.

The file doesn't have the excel extension and we have to choose a program to open the file, that behavior is not wanted. :)

Below is an example on how we set the response header and return a partial view with the model we want to put on excel spreadsheet (from within a controller/action).

```
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/ms-excel");

        return PartialView("~/views/customer/_PlantListPartial.cshtml", plants);
```

How can we achieve what we want and is it even possible? And yes, we run asp.net core on .net framework, not .net core framework.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more header:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.xls"
```

Comment: As you can see from the post from my co-worker, this didn't help. Do you have any other suggesstions?

Comment: Use Fiddler or other tool to capture returned HTTP headers and add this info to your post please.

Comment: thank you for your effort @Dmitry but we went for another solution, we no longer need to export the view to excel.